# 2 gang standard switch to 1 gang dimmer switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

Hi I'm just curious as to how I would go about replacing my 2 gang living room standard light switch to a 1 gang dimmer switch, I'm in the UK just if that makes a difference to wiring, I can turn the light on and off from in my kitchen and near the hall way in another room. [image: this is what I'm after changing it to I just need to know if it will work and how I'd do it please][image]

Comment: so it's a 3-way switch and you want to replace it with a dimmer?

Comment: @JACK the UK word for 3-way is 2-way.   2-gang means the same as the US, except the form factor of a gang is more square.   Not clear, though, on whether OP means a double switch in a 1-gang form factor (freeing a gang space for something else), or a single switch action which operates two lights.

Comment: There are several  different ways this could be wired at the switch. Only one of those ways will allow you to do that.  We need to see how the switch area is wired.  Can you a) turn off the power, b) pull the switches  out of the wall without disconnecting any wires, and c) shoot photos and post them here?  [edit] your post, and click the "mountain and moon" icon to insert a photo. Limit 2 photos until you get more reputation score.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the light switch boxes involved please?

Comment: They make a 3 way switch with a dimmer. In the states. Try it.

Comment: The first picture shows a slot saying 1 way and 2 way the other slot that the red wire is leading to is com